# vertical align issues

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I have a wrapper at 100% and two divs inside. The top div needs to be at the top of the wrapper and the bottom div needs to be at the bottom of the wrapper. It isn't working.

Here is what I have. I've tried vertical-align on both inner divs but it doesn't work either.

```
<style>
#wrap {
width:210px;
height:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
#top {
width:200px;
height:100px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border:1px solid green;
}
#btm {
width:200px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form method="post" action="">
      <div id="top">
adf
      </div>
      <div id="btm">
adf
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which browser are you using? Rendering engines are not built alike, nor to specs....

Answer (score 1):

<strike>it seems to be working, i took out position: relative; you don't need it:</strike>

see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kByXS/

edit: i misunderstood your problem:

here it is solved:
http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/kByXS/2/

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div id="top">
            top
        </div>
        <div id="btm">
            bottom
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
html {
  height: 100%;   
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
#wrap {
    width:210px;
    height:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
#top {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  border:1px solid green;
}
#btm {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
 left: 5px;
}
```

keys:

1. give the html and body 100% height first, then your div will stretch 100% vertically.
2. give your container a `position: relative` with no left or top values,
3. give your bottom div a `position: absolute` (which makes it relative to the container div), and `bottom: 0;`

Comment: What I see is a wrapper that is stretched to the same height as the btom and top divs combined. It looks the same to me in your example as it does in my form. Make the height of the wrapper 100% and then you'll see that the inner divs are stacked on on top of the other.

Comment: Yes  Sebastian, that does work. Thank you. I have a question though... I can't add 100% height to my form because it will stretch the entire site. I only want a 100% height on the wrapper. That wrapper is a sidebar within the site.

Comment: can you give it a pixel height?

Comment: Yes, that I can do however, just for fun, I deleted the 100% height on your html and body elements and it is still working. Am I ok this way or do I need to specify a height>

Comment: Wait a minute.. I see a problem with this... I can't use absolute positioning because the bottom div will come out of the wrapper and go to the floor of my site. I want the wrapper to go to the floor of its parent div. This wrapper is set within the site and is wrapped in other divs.

Comment: i say if it looks ok on every browser, stick with it. if note, you might ened a height. hard to tell without seeing the specific code. good luck mate

Comment: didn't see that last comment.  ok: if you give something a relative position, you can place elements inside that div using position absolute, and it will be positioned relative to its parent div.  does that make sens?

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. Let me try this inside my actual site. I'll be right back

Comment: @Sebastian, I was correct, with absolute positioning, the bottom div is tossed out of the wrapper and is now sitting on the floor of my site instead of the floor of the wrapper.

Comment: did you give your wrapper dive position: relative?

Comment: Yes, I also changed the inner bottom div to relative from absolute which now brings it up to the top. This is not correct either.

Comment: its an example where the bottom div has position:absolute and is not outside the #wrapper div

Comment: ok: #wrap {position: relative} #btm{position: absolute; bottom 0}

Comment: that is the correct markup, if you give your wrap a position absolute. god knows where it will end up.  can you send me link or something where i can see the actual code? i'm sure this is simpler that we're making it out to be

Comment: I'm on a development machine and the code isn't on a server but I can post every bit of the html and css. Would that be ok>

Comment: OK, I don't have an account with jsfiddle. Do I need one?

Comment: takes 1 minute, totally worth it, that way i can see the code in action

Comment: I'll sign up now. I think I posted it anyway

Comment: @Jim: could you add the `<table>` tags that the `<td>` is included in? `<td>` doesn’t make any sense on its own.

Comment: ummmm... i see your code, but where's the wraper div with the top and bottom div in your example?

Comment: `content_left` is the wrapper, `sidebarmenu` should be top aligned and `wr` is what needs to be on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I should have mentioned that the padding-top`margin-top:191px;` in the `wr` div needs to be removed. I was using that to push the bottom div to the floor. It looks good though. Let me try it

Comment: i think i finally get the question.  the problem is that #content_left is a table cell, not a div

Comment: Unfortunately for me, you're right. It isn't working and I am getting sort of impatient with this css and for taking up your time. I posted this last night and still couldn't get anyone to figure it out. I am certain that I can do this with a table design and is probably what I'm going to do.

Comment: Yes, it is a table cell. Does it make a difference?

Comment: ok, here you go, this hsould be it: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/RbVbv/7/

Comment: re: does it make a difference: tooootally! i wrapped your two divs inside a wrapper div and got the result i hope you wanted.

Comment: Wow, that truly looks like a winner! I'm afraid to try it. :)  brb.

Comment: Arggggg...... No Sebastian, it's still aligning to the top of the wrapper. Let me ask you.. Is what I am trying to achieve here considered to be advanced css or something?

Comment: can you post the actual code you're using now?  (color me obsessive). i guess you could call it advanced css.  truth is, and please don't take this the wrong way, you shouldn't be using tables for layout.  you might benefit from teaming up with a decent html/css guy/girl.

Answer (score 1):

In which browser is it not working? Looks fine to me in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Paul, the wrapper div is 100% which is not evident by your screenshot. I've just tried it in FF and Chrome and it is not working.

Comment: @Jim — I’ve pasted the code you’ve supplied into a file, and the screenshot is how that code renders in Chrome, and Firefox for that matter. Are you looking at it in a different browser, in which `#wrap` is taller that it appears in the screenshot? If so, which browser?

Comment: Paul, I have FF, Chrome as well as Opera and it renders exactly the same in all of them. Are you aware that the wrapper div **must be at a 100% height**?

Comment: @Jim — yup, I’ve got all of your supplied code, including the 100% height declaration on `#wrap`. See [http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/4219348/](http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/4219348/). If [Sebastian’s updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219348/vertical-align-issues/4219416#4219416) hasn’t solved your problem, could you please post the complete HTML and CSS that you’re looking at? Otherwise we can’t help you.

Comment: Actually, it hasn't solved my issue because he is using absolute positioning and I can't use that.

Comment: @Paul. I've posted all of the code I have up top. What else do you need? lol. I looked at your example in Opera and Chrome and I see two divs stacked one on top of the other. Please stretch the outtermost div to a 100% height or a fixed height so that I can see a space between the two divs.

Comment: @Jim? Could you view source on my example? It’s the code you posted in your question. Note the presence of **`#wrap {width:210px;height:100%;`** in it, lines 11–13. I’m not sure where the difference is coming in, but I haven’t changed the code you posted in your question, so please check it against your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#wrap{ 
width:210px;
height:100%;
border:1px solid red;
position:relative;
}

#top {
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border:1px solid green;
}
#btm {
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what's happening in a little bit more depth?

Comment: @wajiw, Both inner divs are top aligned, stacked on top of one another

Comment: The bottom inner div needs to be on the bottom of the wrapper

Comment: oh, add "float:left;" to the #top and #btm divs then.

Comment: I just added them but still no dice. These inner divs will not align properly.

Comment: Yeah I don't get what's happening then I guess.  How do you need them to align?  Is there content inside those divs that you need to match up?

Comment: If the wrapper is say for example, 1000px tall, I want the btm div to be on the floor of the wrapper and I want the top div to be on the ceiling of the wrapper.

Comment: Oh ok, then add top:0px; to #top and bottom:0px; to #btm.  You may have to remove the floats on those to get it to work properly.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything either. It looks exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try setting your #wrap to an explicit height greater than the combo of the child divs heights?